# Sort AngularJS ng-repeat with dictionary data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a dictionary (key-value pairs), that might look like this:

```
data = {
    "key1": 1000,
    "key2": 2000,
    "key3": 500
}
```

I would like to view this in a table in AngularJS.

I can do it this way:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    <td>{{ key }}</td>
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
</tr>
```

This works fine so far.

Now I would like to have the table sorted by the value. But the `orderBy` filter seems to only work for lists of objects:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | orderBy: 'value'">
```

Has no effect.
How would I sort this by the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`orderBy`** works on a property of object not the way you mentioned in key,value. Also it expects an array as input, not an object.

You can convert it as an array using angular.forEach and use orderBy as follows

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 var data = {"key1": 1000,
        "key2": 2000,
        "key3": 500 }
  
  $scope.data = [];
  angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
      $scope.data.push({
          key: key,
          count: value
      });
  });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="element in data | orderBy:'count'">
        {{ element.key }} ({{ element.count }})
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was aware that the (default) way for orderBy was on list of objects. I was hoping there would be simple hidden way to do this on the other datastructure without having explicitly to convert it in the controller.